# Sum of only those summands that are larger than the arithmetic mean of all summands

Tags: summation, expected-value, means

Assume we have $N$ non-negative numbers $X_1,..., X_N$ with the arithmetic mean $\bar{X}$.

What is the expected value of the portion of their sum that the summands larger than $\bar{X}$ account for?

Example: $1, 3, 4, 6, 8$. Only $6$ and $8$ are larger than the mean. $6+8=14$, which is $\approx64\%$ of the total sum $22$.

This has very practical applications, e.g. "What portion of our sales do the items that sell better than average account for?"

In general, the aforementioned portion can be anywhere between $0$ and $1$. E.g. for $0, 0, 0, 1$, the portion is $100\%$. For $1, 1, 1, 2$, the portion is $40\%$ and tends to $0\%$ as we add more numbers $1$.

And yet there seem to be patterns. For instance, in my numerical experiments with uniformly distributed random variables, the portion seems to be around $75\%$.

Comment: This is not clear.  What distribution were the $X_i$ chosen from?

Comment: If one of the $X_i$s is equal to the mean $\bar{X}$, then it could be removed without changing the mean.

Comment: Expected value is defined for probabilities, so you need that $X_i$ are random variables, and the answer will probably depend on the distribution(s) of these variables.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out the thing with probability distributions. I was wondering if there was a general approach to this problem, but I'm particularly interested in the cases of uniform and normal distributions of $X_i$.

Comment: As a general matter, for $n$ large, and the $X_i$ i.i.d., the average will be close to the average of the distribution. So for a uniform random variable on $[0,1]$ we expect $n/2$ in $[0,1/2]$ and $n/2$ in $[1/2,1],$ so we expect a total of $\frac n2$ and $\frac{n}2\cdot \frac{3}{4}$ for the total of above-average, and thus a ration of $\frac34.$ Getting this rigorously seems to be a little tricky.

Comment: Note that I’d the random distribution is not positive, it is possible for the denominator to be very small while the numerator is very positive. A simple example is a uniform random variable on $[-1,1].$ Similarly, if the random variables are uniform from $[k,k+1]$ for $k$ large, you might expect the ratio to be $\frac{4k+3}{8k+4}.$